# Multi Valued Function

Tags: complex-numbers

In a book I am reading I have read the following:

> The function $w=\sqrt{z+1}$ is defined on the plane and it is two-valued because the square root has two values for example: $w(0)=-1$, $w(0)=1$

I get that $w^2=z+1$ has $2$ roots in particular at $z=0$, but $w=\sqrt{z+1}$?

Answer (score 2):

The implied context is the **complex plane** and analytic functions of one complex variable. The use of analytic continuation leads to the concept of [**Riemann surface**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface) and also to "multi-valued functions" such as $\sqrt{z}$ and $\log(z)$ which are the functional inverses of nice analytic functions such as $z^2$ and $e^z$ respectively. This also leads to **branch cuts** and **principal values**. Read the Wikipedia
article for more details. So, depending on interpretation, $\sqrt{z}$ is either multi-valued, or else single valued using the principal value but has a branch cut where it is discontinuous.